# [Hibernate]Access Cache memory before BATCH commit

Tags: hibernate, caching

I want to access cache memory before batch commit in Hibernate.
I am counting users up-to BATCH_SIZE then

```
if (countUsers == BATCH_SIZE) {
    countUsers = 0;
    session.flush();
    session.clear();
    transaction.commit();
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()
        .getCurrentSession();
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
}
```

What I am doing is I am storing 30 rows in cahce and then saving it to database. but I also want information of those cached rows before saving them to database.

How to do it?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to see what rows hit the cache and what rows are stored in DB? In that case something like log4j may help

Comment: i don't understand why you want to access the data from cache when you would have the data in a list from which you are iterating and committing using batch commit.

Answer (score 0):

all you have to set the hibernates jdbc batch size attribute and being sure about the transaction management

```
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
```

you can see my [previuos post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972853/hibernate-batch-insert-batch-update) on this subject