# Hibernate batch insert, batch update

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, jdbc, spring-batch

I have dao which basically inserts a record into a table using hibernate, this dao is marked by `@Transactional` annotation with `propogation-NESTED`, and I have service which makes some other stuff and then invokes my dao. My service is also annotated with `@Transactional` with `propagation-REQUIRED`.

I call service in a loop. Does my inserts on my dao works in batch or one by one? How can I be sure that they work in batch? Does hibernateTransaction manager manage batch inserts?

I am using Oracle DB.

Comment: I am asking about JDBC's addBatch equivalent in hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have set following property and my performance increased;

```
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
```

Answer (score 0):

I am no Hibernate expert but I remember adding a property to log out the sql statements.

```
     SessionFactory sf = new Configuration()
       .setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true")
```

This should show what sql is being produced after each execution of your method

Comment: I can trace sql statements, no problem at this point, They seem to appear at once but how can I be sure that they work in batch in DB, if I have used Jdbc and addBatch method then it works in batch in DB. But what about in hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

It will not go in a batch, have a look at [Hibernate Doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html).

Answer (score 0):

To track if hibernate uses batches you may create logger for org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher it will log batcher...