# Calling insert multiple times in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

hi i have an application in which i first check the value in the DB table if not present generate a new value and insert into the DB,this loop goes around a million times,how can i speed it up??

in my working class:-

```
session=HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();       
    for(----loop 

    i check

    i generate

    then:-

    MyTable myTable=new MyTable();
            myTable.setName("dasdas");
            myTable.setww("ss");
            myTable.setaa("daaasdas");

    hibernateRepositoy.save(dgCcno,session);

}
```

save method i the other class:-

```
  public void save(Object obj,Session session)  {       

            Transaction tx = null;
            try {
                tx = session.beginTransaction();
                session.saveOrUpdate(obj);
                session.flush();

                session.clear();
                tx.commit();
            }
            catch (HibernateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);            

                if(tx!=null){
                    tx.rollback();
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);        

            }
        }
```

how can i speed this up, or is this the right approach?

Added:-  i cant use batch update, i have to insert the value right away, cause the values in the next select query can be the same.. and  have to give the value from the DB then

Comment: You can use hibernate batch. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972853/hibernate-batch-insert-batch-update for more details.

Comment: @tibtof no i cant, i have to insert the value right away, cause the values in the next select query can be the same.. and  have to give the value from the DB then

Comment: do you have to commit right away? I think that if you use only one transaction it will be much faster.

Comment: ys cause if i dont commit, and the next value in the select query is the same,so it will generate the same value to be inserted again..

Comment: try to change your transaction isolation level to read uncommited

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- don't use one transaction per row, but include everything (or at least significant subsets) in a single transaction
- issue a single query to verify the existence of several rows at once
- follow the [advices of the reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#batch-inserts)

Comment: plz check the updated question, i have to insert the values right away

Comment: In a given transaction, everything you have inserted is visible to this transaction. So you can execute the next query, and it will find your inserted row, even if the transaction is not committed. The only important this is that the session must be flushed. But Hibernate is smart enough to flush it automatically before executing the query.

Comment: i will just try it out, so can u tell me is there a limit of the objects that i can save before i call tx.commit(). like if i have to save around 1 million records?

Comment: It probably depends on the size of your rollback segment. Try various sizes and sse what works, and what's the most efficient.

Comment: but there is just one problem if another thread comes in and has same values, so??